# set a tag equivalent for UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController named imagePicker

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePicker;
```

Im using the method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

and I need to know which imagePicker is being used, for example, you can set a tag for others such as UIAlertView etc, is their an equivalent for UIImagePickerController? Or how will I tell which is being called.

Comment: it's just .view.tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
   if(picker == _imagePicker)
       //do your task
}
```

or set tag like:

```
imagePicker.view.tag = 7;
```

then check like:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
   if(picker.view.tag == 7)
       //do your task
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the different image pickers you have as properties. Then just compare their pointer values:

```
if (picker == self.picker1) {
    // ...
} else if (picker == self.picker2) {
    // ...
} ...
```

When you are done with the pickers, set their properties to nil to allow them to be cleaned up.

If you really want to 'tag' them, you can use [Objective-C associative references](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/).

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish between `UIImagePickerViewController`'s with the same `sourceType` you could introduce a new entity `Role`:

```
fileprivate enum ImagePickerRole {
   case avatar
   case chooseImage
   case takePhoto
}

fileprivate class ImagePicker: UIImagePickerController {
   private(set) var role: ImagePickerRole = .takePhoto
}

fileprivate extension ImagePicker {
   convenience init(role imagePickerRole: ImagePickerRole) {
      self.init()
      role = imagePickerRole
      switch role {
         case .avatar, .takePhoto:
            sourceType = .camera
            cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            showsCameraControls = true
         case .chooseImage:
            sourceType = .photoLibrary
      }
}
```

Further in your `UIImagePickerViewControllerDelegate` you can check the role of the controller:

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    guard let imagePicker = picker as? ImagePicker else { return }

    switch imagePicker.role {
    case .avatar:
        // Your code here
    case .takePhoto:
        // Your code here
    case .chooseImage:
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would save instance of imagepicker to ivar or property. After you just check if it's the same instance.

```
@interface MyImagePicker : UIViewController
{
    UIImagePickerController * _ imagePicker;
}   

@implementation 
- (void)showImagePicker {
   _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   //config and show
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
if(picker == _imagePicker) {
  //My picker do stuff here
}
```

Comment: This is unfortunately totally wrong. The entire point of the question is to distinguish between different pickers which may be running.